# Blender Painting now showing

Tags: blender

I'm pretty new to Blender and I'm trying to make some models underground dungeons similar to dungeon siege. I'm not sure but I think they use texture painting to add some variety to the walls.

In any case, i unwrapped the mesh with smart uv project option, I made a material and added a new image texture. Then i went on texture paint mode, clecked on slots and put the image created before.

Then clicked on tools and tried to paint...strength of paint is 5, blend=mix but nothing happens when i try to paint in the 3d view.

Also yesterday, after painting some things I imported all to unity to see how it was like and is seemed all out of focus.

I'm pretty desperate in texturing or painting things, hope somebody can help.

Comment: ok solved one of my issues. Had to go in edit mode and CTRL+N on mesh. Hope someone will help on other things.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Resolution of your Image Texture.
If it is to low it could be the Reason for the Strange Appearance in Unity.